# Resetting password after submit doesn't change password

Tags: php

I am trying to reset password but after I submit new password it takes me back to login without changing it. I think this happens because it doesn't remember the email and token. It shows me the form but after I click submit doesn't do anything.

Code:

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['email']) && isset($_GET['token'])) {
include('databaze.php');
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$email = $conn->real_escape_string($_GET['email']);
$token = $conn->real_escape_string($_GET['token']);

  $data = $conn->query("SELECT did FROM tbldoc WHERE email='$email' AND 
  token='$token'");
if ($data->num_rows > 0) {
    include('reset-form.php');
    if (isset($_POST['resetPass'])) {
        $password = $_POST["password"];
        $password_conf = $_POST['password-conf'];
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $token = $_POST["token"];
        if (empty($password) || empty($password_conf)) {
            echo "<br><br>Fill the form";
        } elseif ($password !== $password_conf) {
            echo "<br><br>Password doesn't match Password Confirmation";
        }
        $password = md5($password);

        $conn->query("UPDATE tbldoc SET hashedpwd='$password', token='' WHERE email='$email'");


    }
} else {

    echo "Please check your link!";

  }
} else {

   header("Location: login.php");
   exit();
 }
?>
```

form:

```
 <form method="post" action="resetpassword.php" class="form-signin">
<h2 class="form-signin-heading">Reset Password</h2>
Password <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
<br>

Password Confirmation <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password-conf"
                             placeholder="Password Confirmation">
<br>
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="token" value="<?php echo $token;?>">


<input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" name="resetPass" value="Reset your Password">
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Your form is type **POST** and you are expecting **GET**

```
isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['token'])
```

Could be?

Answer (score 0):

Your form action is `post` method so you need to check the condition as

`if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['token']))`

This is full code. you use some place `GET` and some place `POST` method so it will work for `POST` method...

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['token'])) {
include('databaze.php');
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$email = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$token = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['token']);

  $data = $conn->query("SELECT did FROM tbldoc WHERE email='$email' AND 
  token='$token'");
if ($data->num_rows > 0) {
    include('reset-form.php');
    if (isset($_POST['resetPass'])) {
        $password = $_POST["password"];
        $password_conf = $_POST['password-conf'];
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $token = $_POST["token"];
        if (empty($password) || empty($password_conf)) {
            echo "<br><br>Fill the form";
        } elseif ($password !== $password_conf) {
            echo "<br><br>Password doesn't match Password Confirmation";
        }
        $password = md5($password);

        $conn->query("UPDATE tbldoc SET hashedpwd='$password', token='' WHERE email='$email'");


    }
} else {

    echo "Please check your link!";

  }
} else {

   header("Location: login.php");
   exit();
 }
?>
```

or change your form like `<form method="GET" action="resetpassword.php" class="form-signin">`

Comment: If I use post then directly goes to the last else- login.php.

Comment: print your `POST` data and exit before that `if` condition @Nda.S

Answer (score 0):

May be because of this line, your SQL is not able to search email

```
$email = $conn->real_escape_string($_GET['email']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your form. It will remember the email and token:

```
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo @$email; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo @$token; ?>">
```

Comment: Why do you use @ ?

Comment: @ will hide notifications on empty variable in case you have error reporting on

Answer (score 0):

Your `form` method is `POST` and you are checking the data in `GET`. So every time else part will be called. change this line in your code

```
if (isset($_GET['email']) && isset($_GET['token'])) {
```

with

```
if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['token'])) {
```